# how to validate a form with Aurelia

Tags: polymer, aurelia

I  have created the following form using Polymer and Aurelia.

```
    <form is="iron-form" id="frmLogOn">
      <paper-input value.bind="endisableform()" id="txtInput" ...></paper-input>
    <paper-button id="btnLogOn">Log On</paper-button>
    </form>
```

In the viewmodel I have a method called endisableform() that is being called.

I want to validate a button on the form using frmLogOn.validate() but the viewmodel does not know about the form frmLogOn.

The validate method is provided by the iron-form element.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand validating a button on a form (which can't be manipulated) but here is how you can give your view-model a nice reference to your form -

```
<form is="iron-form" id="frmLogOn" ref="frmLogOn">
  <paper-input value.bind="endisableform()" id="txtInput" ...></paper-input>
<paper-button id="btnLogOn">Log On</paper-button>
</form>
```

Then in your view-model -

```
export class MyViewModel {
  endisableform() {
    if (this.frmLogOn.something) {
      console.log('something was ok');
    }
  }
}
```